# Canon 6D Mark ii RAW preview on Mac not displaying

Tags: canon, lightroom, photoshop, raw, canon-6d

Anyone else having this issue? The thumbnails/previews on my Mac for my RAW files (taken with my 6D Mark ii) are not displaying and are just showing the photoshop/RAW icon... im assuming this is some sort of software update issue but just in case it isn't does anyone know what the problem/fix is?

Comment: This is a near universal occurrence when new camera models come out. It takes the other players (Adobe, Windows, Mac, etc) a few weeks to update their products to make them compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6D MkII is not supported yet.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207049